# How to disable cache on view with ID as contextual filter

Tags: views, 8, blocks, caching

I've got a view (block) wich fetches images from all nodes of content type x. I use these in a slider.

When I open node y, I only want to see the image of node y. So I add a contextual filter to filter on this node.

Here's the thing... It doesn't work. It caches the image, and always shows the cashed image. I already set the view caching to 'none' and disabled page caching.

I've got no clue how to disable the caching for this. Is this view caching? Is this block caching? Is this page caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: I am using slick views for the slider.

Slick itself has cashing options. After disabling that caching, it worked like a charm.

to disable: 
* edit your view
* open the format settings
* Scroll down to the cache settings
* Set it to no caching